# problem with case sensitivity in acts_as_ferret

Tags: ruby, acts-as-ferret, ferret

I have a problem with case sensitivity - basically, searches only work 
when they are lowercase: even when it looks like the text stored in the index 
is uppercase.

How to deal with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String's downcase method?